Why don't Solar Eclipses take place frequently?
To my understanding, a Solar eclipse occurs when the moon (Luna) passes in front of the sun, blocking it completely from the viewer's perspective (I also know that the moon takes roughly one month to complete an orbit around the earth). Firstly, here's what I used to think:

IMAGE NOT TO SCALE
If point A is at a Solar eclipse, shouldn't the moon be in front of the Earth somewhere near point B again?
I realized I was gravely wrong and instead came up with this hypothesis:

IMAGE NOT TO SCALE
I imagine this would mean the solar eclipse can only take place at the "Point of solar eclipse," which would also happen during a specific time. However, I am still quite unsure. Could anyone please explain what happens during the solar eclipse and why it doesn't happen too frequently?

Better asked on Astronomy. Also trivial to google the answer.

Actually solar eclipses happen more often than you might think. Counting both partial and total solar eclipses there is an eclipse at least every six months, and sometimes even more frequent, in some cases just a month apart. Total eclipses are pretty common also, if you include annular eclipses they occur in a series of a total/annual solar eclipse about every six months, then after about 3-5 of them there is a gap of a year or two, then the next series starts. The reason that it seems less frequent is because normally only total eclipses visible in the U.S. or Europe make the headlines.

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eclipse_season

AerospaceNerd - please go back and read the [about] and [help] pages for this site and for Astronomy, to understand the scope of each site better, and to see what types of questions are good questions on each site.

Yes, the moon does indeed orbit the Earth every month.
A solar eclipse occurs when the moon passes directly between the Earth and the Sun, blocking the Sun’s light.
However, eclipses don’t happen every month because the moon's orbit is tilted relative to the Earth's orbit around the Sun. It's called the ecliptic plane (The moon's orbit is tilted by about 5 degrees from Earth's orbit around the Sun).
You've shown that in the diagram. I haven't looked at those too much though because I don't think it's needed.
Most of the time, when the moon passes between the Earth and the Sun (new moon), it is either slightly above or below the line between the Earth and Sun, so it does not block the Sun from our view.
If the moon’s orbit were exactly aligned with Earth's orbit, we’d have a solar eclipse during every new moon and a lunar eclipse during every full moon.
However, because the moon’s orbit is tilted, the moon usually passes slightly above or below the Sun from our perspective during the new moon phase, missing the perfect alignment needed for an eclipse.

A solar eclipse can only occur when two conditions are met:

The moon is in its "new moon" phase (aligned with the Sun).
The moon is near one of the two points where its orbit crosses the Earth’s orbital plane.

The reason we don’t get solar eclipses every month is because of the moon's orbit being tilted relative to Earth's orbit. Solar eclipses only happen during specific times when the moon, Earth, and Sun all align perfectly at the nodes, and this alignment doesn’t occur every new moon, making eclipses relatively rare.

Think of the Earth and the Sun as lying on a flat plane (the ecliptic plane), and the moon’s orbit as a slightly tilted ring around the Earth.
For a solar eclipse to occur, the moon needs to cross this flat plane exactly when it’s also in its new moon phase (directly between the Earth and the Sun).
Even though the moon reaches a new moon once every month, it doesn’t always do so when it’s crossing the ecliptic plane (through the points of eclipse), so eclipses are rare.
However during most months, the moon is slightly too high or too low relative to the Sun at the time of the new moon.

Basically, they would happen more frequently if the moon orbited perfectly equatorially.
